# RSA Prime Generation using Provable vs Probable Prime Construction

Tags: rsa, primes, number-theory

I am trying to implement RSA prime generation for P and Q based on FIP186-4 specification. The specification describes two different implementations: Section 3.2 Provable Prime Construction vs. Section 3.3 Probable Prime Construction. Initially, I tried implementing the probable prime approach because it is easier to understand and implement, but I discovered it is very slow because of the number of iterations needed to find P and Q primes (worst case it takes 15 minutes). Next, I decided to try the provable prime approach but I found out the algorithm is much more complex and might be slow as well. Below are my two issues:

1. In Section C.10, Step 12, how to eliminate the sqrt(2) to the expression x = floor(sqrt(2))(2^(L−1))) + (x mod (2^L − floor((sqrt(2)(2^(L−1))))) so that I can represent it as whole numbers using BigNum representation?
2. In Section C.10, Step 14, is there a fast way to compute y in the interval [1, p2] such that 0 = ( y p0 p1–1) mod p2? The specification doesn't specify a method to implement this. My initial thought was to perform a linear search staring from integer 1 and up but that can be very slow because p2 can be a very large number.

I tried searching online for help on this issue, but I discovered a lot of examples don't even comply with FIPS186-4. I assume it is because these two methods are too slow.

Comment: Did you check OpenSSL? Provable is based on AKS primality test, and yes it is slow. What is your key size? you can check your performance by comparing with OpenSSL via `openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048`, also what is your machine? in I5-8th gen it took less than 1 sec.

Comment: If it takes 15 minutes to generate a probable prime either you're using a PC from late 1980s or you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. After review my probable prime implementation again, I spotted some round off errors that I fixed. On a PowerPC 1.5Ghz, I am now getting the following benchmarks (on average): 2048 bits is 35 sec, 3072 bits is 216 sec, and 4096 bits is 402 sec.

Comment: You may want to look at GnuTLS, `--provable` and `--seed` options of [`certtool`](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/certtool-Invocation.html#certtool-provable) allow you to generate a key using FIPS PUB186-4 algorithms.